# How to make an xml page appear upon button click

Tags: android

I am very new to Android programming. I've been to the online documentation and lurked around here for a while but am utterly frustrated. I'm making an app for English learners and have used big nerd ranch to help understand mobile development. Upon first run a welcome pop up appears. Then the user is presented with three buttons. My problem lies in how to make a button upon click pull up a new xml page. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Dave

Comment: by saing 'xml page' you mean layout you define in res/layout directory?

Comment: just create a new activity or fragment.

Answer (score 0):

if you question means opening a new `activity` that includes a `.java` and `.xml` files .

`Intent newIntent= new Intent(the_activity_you_in.this, the_new_activity.class) .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

`startActivity(newIntent);`

the code above is used to open a new activity in the activity that your in, you use intent to specify the transaction you want to do,such that , the first attribute `the_activity_you_in.this` specifies where you are now,the second attribute  `the_new_activity.class` specifies where you want to go , `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` is used to give this intent high priority so its starts first.

hope that helpend.

Comment: I want to move from home_screen to lesson_list by clicking a button. lesson_list will display a list of all available lessons to click. I am confused as to how to get it to show. The syntax is very new to me, as is the Android API.

Comment: update is underlined in red too, can you explain that?

Comment: @user3718523 my bad sorry , i updated my answers and added some explanation . if that helped mark it as true so anyone who check this questions knows the right answer.